# There is a problem using react navigation 3 in real device

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have one materialBottomTabNav and inside this materialBottomTabNav I have stackNavigator. For couple of weeks I am develeoping StackNav inside MaterialBottomTabBar or vice versa.

**Here is the App.js**

```
class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <BottomNavigator/>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

**bottomNavigator.js**

```
const BottomTabNavigator1 = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator({

    HomeContainer : {
        screen : HomeContainer
    },
    OrdersPage : {
        screen : OrdersPage
    },
    ProfilePage : {
        screen : ProfilePage
    }
},


);

const BottomTabNavigator = createAppContainer(BottomTabNavigator1)

export default BottomTabNavigator;
```

**homeContainer.js**(Stack Nav which is inside material bottom bar)

```
const HomeCapsule = createStackNavigator({

    ScreenOne : {
        screen : ScreenOne
    },
    ScreenTwoPage : {
        screen : ScreenTwo
    },
    ScreenThree : {
        screen : ScreenThree
    }
},


);

const HomeContainer = createAppContainer(HomeCapsule)

export default HomeContainer;
```

There can a big gap with this navigation API. I have tried three different Android Phones. inside Stack this.props.navigation.navigate does not work. The funny part is for three weeks all of my navigation nested designs work in Android Emulator. They are all working. But when I run them in real device I am really loosing hope. After two months now I have to change something inside my app.

**Github Repo for trying**

https://github.com/selimmidikoglu/react-navigation3

Just clone code from here and try to run it on your own android device to reproduce.

Comment: We can't help you without knowing what the problem is on the real device. Here is an example that might help you though. Please check the link. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html

Comment: @FatihAktaş Abi gerçekten kafayı yemek üzereyim. tab navigation ile stack navigation ın çalışmama olayı çok saçma. Repoyu clone layıp Android telefonun varsa deneyebilir misin? Samsun, Nokia falan hiç birinde olmuyor.

Comment: For future reader of this question, there was a problem with mobx and babel configuration. While using mobx be careful about how you set up babel. That was the problem for me.